# PrimeFaces 3.2 selsectOneMenu valueChangeListener not working

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, primefaces

i wish to retrieve List based on the selection of dropdownlist item. for that i am using the following code which is not working:

```
<p:selectOneMenu style="width: 150px" value="#{watchBean.exchange}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="NSE" itemValue="nse"/>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="BSE" itemValue="bse"/>            
                <p:ajax event="change" update=":frm" listener="#{watchBean.doScripList}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
```

bean code:

```
    public void doScripList(ValueChangeEvent e)
{

    sl=getAllScripByExchange((String)e.getNewValue());  //sl is of type List<MasterScrip>
}
```

when i debug , i see that the event is not fired and i get the following error:

```
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: beans.watchBean@9ac2e4.doScripList(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)
at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.getMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:155)...
```

when i omit p:ajax the 'exchange' type is also not get/set
what is causing this problem? what is its solution?

**edited**
renamed the method to wow() still the same error :

```
 javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: beans.watchBean@1732d83.wow(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)
```

**edited** : managed bean code

```
 import java.util.List;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceRef;
import service.MasterScrip;
import service.StatelessWebService_Service;
@Named(value = "watchBean")
@RequestScoped
public class watchBean {
    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/localhost_8080/StatelessWebService/StatelessWebService.wsdl")
    private StatelessWebService_Service service;

    /** Creates a new instance of watchBean */
    public watchBean() {
    }
    String uname,scripSym,exchange;
    Integer scripID;
    List<UserTrack> ut;
List<MasterScrip> sl;
    public List<MasterScrip> getSl() {
        return sl;
    }

    public void setSl(List<MasterScrip> sl) {
        this.sl = sl;
    }


    public String getExchange() {
        return exchange;
    }

    public void setExchange(String exchange) {
        sl=getAllScripByExchange(exchange);
        this.exchange = exchange;
    }
public void wow(ValueChangeEvent e)
{    
    sl=getAllScripByExchange((String)e.getNewValue());
   // setSl(sl);
    //FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();

    // sl=getAllScripByExchange(exchange);
}
```

Comment: for sanity check : try to rename your `doScripList` into something like `wow` and try it with `<p:ajax listener="#{watchBean.wow}"`.... (restart your web server...)

Comment: as you can see the answer given below by @Sai Ye Yan Naing Aye, it says that its a bug in primefaces 3.2 . is it true? or should i go with ur solution?

Comment: I wouldn't count on "its a bug" without link to open issue + his given solution is from JSF 1...

Comment: renamed the method to wow() still the same error :  javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: beans.watchBean@1732d83.wow(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)

Comment: check your imports, somethiong like this ? `import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;`

Comment: edited my to include managed bean code, i have checked it, pls check it once if you find any errors...

Comment: try changing `@Named(value = "watchBean")` into `ManagedBean` and `@RequestScoped` into `import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;` use the exact imports i told you before... b.t.w are you really working with CDI ?

Comment: `import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;` (i already wrote that above...)

Comment: imported the required imports as you suggested, but still the method is not called and this time no error is encountered, where am i wrong?

Comment: you placed break point inside the method?

Comment: yeah i kept it inside the method at sl=... sry for my previous comment, the method is not called AND the error is still shown - method not found wow()

Comment: remove `event="change"` and make sure the `selectOneMenu` is inside a form and there are not nested forms

Comment: did so still the same error : javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: beans.watchBean@2e1b13.wow(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
<p:ajax event="change" update=":frm" listener="#{watchBean.doScripList}" />
```

to

```
<p:ajax event="change" update=":frm" listener="#{watchBean.doScripList()}" />
```

add parenthesis at the end of the method.

JSF is looking for a method `setDoScripList` in your backing bean, but when adding the parenthesis at the end you're calling this method `doScripList` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Landed on the same problem as yours, but I figured out that the valueChangeListener

```
public void doScripList(ValueChangeEvent e)
```

works only when you use `<f:ajax>` tag and not when you use `<p:ajax>`.
But since selectOneMenu is of type `<p:selectOneMenu>`, so `<f:ajax>` won't work.

I worked out by removing the parameter `ValueChangeEvent e` and it worked.
So try out a no-parameter listener in case of `<p:ajax>` tag.

```
public void doScripList()
{
    sl=getAllScripByExchange(getExchangeName());
}
```

Note: here you don't have the event parameter so, it sets the new value by calling respective setter methods, and you can access updated values in the listener.
For this case you also need to provide id to selectOneMenu like this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="exchangeName" style="width: 150px" value="#{watchBean.exchange}">
  ...
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

and then you add get and set methods for exchangeName in your Bean class:

```
private String exchangeName;

public String getExchangeName(){
   return exchangeName;
}

public void setExchangeName(String exchangeName) {
    this.exchangeName = exchangeName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is primefaces 3.2 bug, please replace your code as the following.

```
  <h:selectOneMenu style="width: 150px" value="#{watchBean.exchange}" valueChangeListener="#{watchBean.doScripList}" onchange="submit()">
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="NSE" itemValue="nse"/>
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="BSE" itemValue="bse"/>            
   </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Change your method likes here;

```
  public void doScripList(ValueChangeEvent e){
     sl = getAllScripByExchange((String)e.getNewValue());
     setAllScriptExchange(sl);  //please write setAllScriptExchange method yourself
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
  }
```

Your page is reloaded, because of onchange event.

Comment: did so, now the method is called, but the page is reloaded i dont know why , and the list variable is again set to null

Comment: i am working on cascading droprown n as per ur solution, the 2nd dropdown its filling meaning that the list is again set to null i guess, what to do?

Comment: You mean sl is a type of List<MasterScript>, so please change sl to String datatype. selectOneMenu accept only one value once a time. I mean "String sl = getAllScriptByExchange((String)e.getNewValue())"please try this.